# Не могу считать каждую секунду из локального времени

Tags: java, android, дата

Нужно сделать будильник.А для этого нужно считать каждую секунду из системного времени.Делаю это в цикле  `AsyncTask.doInBackground();` И когда вывожу текущее время после `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` время он показывает ту что было при инициализации.Как быть? Вот код :

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        Date date = new Date();
        String month  = (String) DateFormat.format("MM",   date); 
        String day      = (String) DateFormat.format("dd",   date);         
        String hour  = (String) DateFormat.format("HH",   date);
        String min  = (String) DateFormat.format("mm",   date);

        Log.e("month : ",""+month);
        Log.e("day   : ",""+day);
        Log.e("hour  : ",""+hour);
        Log.e("min   : ",""+min); 
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                boolean bool = true;
                while(bool){
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     hour  = (String) DateFormat.format("HH",   date);
                     min  = (String) DateFormat.format("mm",   date);
                     dayss        = (String) DateFormat.format("dd",   date); 
                     monthNumber  = (String) DateFormat.format("MM",   date); 

                     mont = Integer.valueOf(monthNumber);
                     day = Integer.valueOf(dayss);
                     hours = Integer.valueOf(hour);
                     minutes = Integer.valueOf(min);


                     //Log.e("mont : ",""+mont);
                     //Log.e("day : ",""+day);
                     Log.e("hours : ",""+hours);//Тут ничего не меняется
                     Log.e("minutes : ",""+minutes);//Тут ничего не меняется 

                }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Ну, вы создаёте дату при инициализации, что вы хотите? Пересоздавайте дату внутри цикла, или используйте календарь.

Comment: @test123 Ясн.спс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пересоздавайте дату в цикле:

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Date date;
        boolean bool = true;
        while(bool){
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            date = new Date(); // Пересоздание даты
            String hour = (String) DateFormat.format("HH",   date);
            String min  = (String) DateFormat.format("mm",   date);
            String dayss        = (String) DateFormat.format("dd",   date); 
            String monthNumber  = (String) DateFormat.format("MM",   date); 

            int mont = Integer.valueOf(monthNumber);
            int day = Integer.valueOf(dayss);
            int hours = Integer.valueOf(hour);
            int minutes = Integer.valueOf(min);


            //Log.e("mont : ",""+mont);
            //Log.e("day : ",""+day);
            Log.e("hours : ",""+hours);//Тут ничего не меняется
            Log.e("minutes : ",""+minutes);//Тут ничего не меняется 

        }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: А каждую секунду создавать это нормально?

Comment: @maks_007, касательно форматтеров, они тут так же не нужны. Почитайте про unixtime формат, и для извлечения минут секунд часов и т.д. используйте математику, а не это извращение...

Comment: @maks_007, дата - это обёртка над unixtime числом. Создавать её не очень затратно. Если боитесь, смотрите в сторону календаря, или извлекайте системный unixtime штамп.

Comment: Как пример, системное время можно извлечь так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177552/how-do-i-create-a-unix-timestamp-on-android